# How to use transaction in MongoDB 4.0 using QueryDSL and Morphia?

Tags: mongodb, groovy, spring-data, querydsl, morphia

I'm using QueryDSL 4.2.1, Morphia 1.3.2 and MongoDB Java Driver 3.5.

After upgrading MongoDB server to version 4.0, I updated the mongo-java-driver to a version that supports transactions in MongoDB.

QueryDSL seems to have abandoned integration with Morphia in version 1.3.2. Maybe the solution is to replace Morphia with Spring Data.

How do I use transactions in MongoDB 4.0 using QueryDSL and Morphia?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about QueryDSL but with Morphia itself, you can start a session via the `Datastore`:

https://morphia.dev/2.0.0/javadoc/dev/morphia/Datastore.html#startSession()

More information can be found here:  https://morphia.dev/2.0.0/guides/transactions/

Comment: The more interesting method is probably withTransaction https://morphia.dev/2.0.0/javadoc/dev/morphia/Datastore.html#withTransaction(dev.morphia.transactions.experimental.MorphiaTransaction)

Comment: QueryDSL was being used as a common language in an application written in Groovy and Java accessing Oracle and Mongo.

To use Mongo transactions, we would have to use newer versions of Morphia, which was not possible because of the integration with QueryDSL.

So we replaced Morphia with Spring Data, but code generation using maven-compiler-plugin had to be replaced by Maven APT plugin also.

The build failed and the solution would be to break application into modules, but this is not what we wanted.

So we decided to abandon QueryDSL.